# Slideshow loop for single long image

Tags: javascript, css

I'm having trouble figuring out the best solution for slideshow with left and right arrows that "pans" in a circular way around a singular image.

I can pan right and then back to the left very easily, but any solutions I can think of to make a looping slideshow seem too complicated.

Here's an explanation of how the slideshow works currently:

1. There is a div containing an image (a skyline) that is longer than
   the viewport width. The overflow is hidden. The image is about 1 and
   half times longer, so some of the skyline is seen on both
   "slides"and this creates a continuity I would like to keep.
2. When the user first loads the page, clicking the left arrow does
   nothing, but I want it bring "itself" into view coming in from the
   left.
3. When the user first loads the page, clicking the right arrow pans
   right, revealing the rest of the skyline.
4. At this point, clicking the left arrow at this point pans back left,
   going back to the beginning.
5. Clicking the right arrow does nothing, but I want it to pan back to
   the beginning with the image coming in from the right.

What I'm missing is that the client wants the left arrow, when on the first slide, to wrap around back to the right side. And if you press the right arrow twice, it wraps around back to the first side. This circularity is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: I'm not sure I clearly understand exactly how you want the panning to work, but I've posted a solution below which is already most of the way there. If you can clarify exactly how you need the panning to be, I can modify the solution, so that it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you describe above by:

1. using `css` to declare a `background-image` (ensuring that it is set to `repeat`); and then
2. using `javascript` to update the `x` co-ordinate of `background-position`:

```js
function pan(direction) {
var landscape = document.getElementsByClassName('landscape')[0];
var backgroundPosition = getComputedStyle(landscape).getPropertyValue("background-position");
var x = parseInt(backgroundPosition);

if (direction === 'left') {
x = x + 600;
}

if (direction === 'right') {
x = x - 600;
}

landscape.style.backgroundPosition = x + 'px 0';
}

var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var left = buttons[0];
var right = buttons[1];

left.addEventListener('click',function(){pan('left');},false);
right.addEventListener('click',function(){pan('right');},false);
```

```css
.landscape {
width: 400px;
height: 150px;
border: 1px solid rgb(255,0,0);
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/bCLGtf3.png') repeat;
background-position: 0 0;
overflow: hidden;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.buttons {
width: 82px;
padding: 12px 160px;
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="landscape">
</div>

<div class="buttons">
<button type="button">&lt;</button>
<button type="button">&gt;</button>
</div>
```

**N.B.** In the example above, the landscape background is `600px` wide, which is one and a half times the width of its `400px` wide container.

Comment: Could a similar method to this shift an entire div and it's containing elements? Also, is there a way to make it work responsively?

Comment: There's a way to make everything work responsively. And yes, a similar method using something like `transform:translate(x,y)` instead of `background-position`, could be used to shift an entire div and its containing elements.

Comment: The problem with this is that it's now no longer circular due the lack of repeating background.